# syncfusion wpf chart array of double - how to use with mvvm

Tags: wpf, syncfusion-chart

I have a Model with an array[100] of double and I would like to use this directly as the data for the chart. The index value should be the X and the value at that index should be the Y on the chart.

Currently I have to convert the array to a list of points (in my ViewModel) where I store the index value (0-99) as the X of the point and the value of that array index as the Y value of the point.

My xaml looks like this :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <syncfusion:SfChart>
            <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                <chart:NumericalAxis/>
            </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                <chart:NumericalAxis/>
            </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <chart:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" XBindingPath="X" YBindingPath="Y"/>
        </syncfusion:SfChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I cannot imagine that this is the best way to get the result ...

Comment: Wouldn't it be fantastic if people down voting questions would leave a small comment why. Maybe I could learn something from it or even modify my question. People asking questions do not do this because they feel like it that day, no, they have a problem or do not know something, that is why they ask questions. In my case I have a GDI+ and QML background and I'm trying to move over to WPF/xaml and mvvm and I'm trying to do things correct. I notice a lot that 'optimizations' are not the priority in both wpf and xaml and that is new for me coming from superfast GDI+ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The index value should be the X and the value at that index should be the Y on the chart.

Well, the only way to let the control know this is to create an object with a property that returns the X value and another that returns the Y value and then set the `XBindingPath` and `YBindingPath` to the names of these respectively. This is MVVM.

The control cannot really be supposed to figure out that you want the index to represent the Y value.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, but I do not want the index to be the y-value BUT the x-value (0-100, like in percentages - not very often used apparently) and to be honest that has nothing to do with mvvm as such. Since I have to say in xaml that the x-axis should be numeric, I think the control knows it can expect numeric values (such as an index for example). Is it therefore so far fetched that maybe a method could be present that allows binding directly to an array ?

Comment: You can bind to an array of  `T` where `T` is a type with a property that represents the X value *and*  a property that represents the Y value, i.e. you cannot bind to an `int[]` or another array of primitive types and expect it work.